# PHP convert WKB to WKT

Tags: php, sqlite, gis, spatialite

I have been trying to figure this out for days.  We have a spatialite database that is read by php and data is returned in a json feed.  I do not have access to spatialite addon to sqlite in my hosting plan.  We are initially trying to find a library or other means of recreating the AsText() function used in mysql.

Our first attempt was using the geoPHP library but they only support small endian.

Below is our initial code using sqlite3. We are able to get the binary but can not figure out how to parse it to text.

```
$db = new SQLite3($checkDB);
$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".$data['table']." LIMIT ". $limit .";" );
while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){ 
  $binary = unpack('H*', $row['GEOMETRY']);
  
  
}
```

It could also be that our unpack is not correct and our binary is incorrect. Below is a sample of what we are receiving

```
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
```

Comment: https://packagist.org/?query=wkb%20parse

Comment: I dont think it is an issue with the package.  I think it has to do with the way it pulls from the database.  Every library errors when trying to read $binary.  because I can not use AsText or AsBinary it has to be returned/modified in some way.